# Buscar dados pelo MySQL no PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, conexão

Existe alguma maneira de conectar o MySQL com PostgreSQL, de maneira que seja utilizado o SGBD do MySQL mas selecionando dados que estejam no PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

Não. Um SGBD, por definição, é o lugar onde os dados estão salvos num formato específico, e um método de interagir com os dados.

Você pode:

- Converter os dados de PostgreSQL para MySQL permanentemente
- Usar um sistema de armazenamento intermediário (Middleware)
- Criar um sistema de APIs para extrair dados do PostgreSQL sem ter que usar a interface dele para todo acesso.